# Storing $award_id in a cookie - PHP

Tags: php, variables, cookies, mybb, coinpayments-api

I have created a MYBB forum [wadakela.xyz](https://wadakela.xyz). I have added [newPoints Awards System](https://community.mybb.com/mods.php?action=view&pid=1010) in it. Which is integrated with [CoinPayments](https://www.coinpayments.net/) for user to buy it.

img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU3G6.png

Now, for example I have 5 awards and user buys 3rd one. I have scripted files which send an email and PM to me notifying that "*this*" user has purchased an award with ''*this award ID*'' when the user gets on success (callback from coinpayment) page.

imgs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRFhC.jpg

Initially, when it was not integrated with coinpayments, I used POST method to get the award ID from the form when someone clicks BUY button through awards page which actually was working fine. I could get the proper id using this code.

```
//awards page
<input type="hidden" name="award" value="{$award['aid']}">

//success page
$award_id = $_POST['award'];
```

Now that it is integrated with *CoinPayments*, it's not going to the *success.php* directly so POST method isn't working. If I'm not wrong, I can get the award id in the *success.ph*p via **cookies** (or sessions maybe?). But, I'm failing to store award ID in a cookie.

**As we know, it's now like this:**

**-awards page -> coinpayments site -> success page.**

To get award ID from *awards page* to *success page*, I tried the following code to store award ID into the cookie:

```
//in awards page
setcookie("award",$award['aid'], time()+300);

//in the form
<input type="hidden" name="award" value="{$award['aid']}">


....processing with coinpayments....



//in success (callback) page
$award_id = $_COOKIE["award"];

echo $award_id;  //pm + email actually.

setcookie("award",$award_id, time()-60);
```

in success page, $award_id Always returns "5". Maybe because there are 5 awards listed?

Other than this, the whole process is very smooth and working as intended. **What I want to do is to store proper award ID in the cookie.**

I'd appreciate if one could help me with this. And if there's any alternate to achieve this, I'd like to know about it as well.

And also, I really need to get it done by today..

If you need more information, please let me know.

Thank you. :)

Comment: It doesn't sound very secure using a cookie like that. When user POSTs the form, you have the award_id (as you mentioned), so call the payment process, and on success do your logic with the posted award_id you already have...

Comment: @Stuart , $_POST['award'] returns "" (empty) on success page. Because it is redirected from coinpayments.net and not from myforum/awards.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success URL doesn't work as IPN. Instead, IPN is required to return POST data.

```
<input type="hidden" name="ipn_url" value="https://wadakela.xyz/YOURIPNFILE.php">
<input type="hidden" name="ipn_type" value="simple">
```

here YOURIPNFILE will return the POSTed data.